# Proplems of generate rig

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to generate a rig for my character. But for some reason, the generated rig doesn't fit my setup metarig. Can anyone help me to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both model and Metarig should have all transform applied (Ctrl A) before generating. Check if your metarig has coordinates 000, 000, 111.

Check Delta transforms also.